# How to subclass AVAudioUnitEffect and implement a custom effect?

Tags: avfoundation, core-audio

I'm currently working with Core Audio, and found AVAudioEngine suits most of my needs. Now I need to make a custom AVAudioUnitEffect, how do I implement one? Or do I need to go back to Core Audio? If I need go back to Core Audio, how can I achieve that(like register a custom AudioUnit?)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to install a processing tap?

```
- (void)installTapOnBus:(AVAudioNodeBus)bus bufferSize:(AVAudioFrameCount)bufferSize format:(AVAudioFormat * nullable)format block:(AVAudioNodeTapBlock nonnull)tapBlock
```

EDIT: according to your comment this does not work.

To create your own AU, you should start with the [PublicUtility](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CoreAudioUtilityClasses/Listings/CoreAudio_AudioUnits_AUPublic_AUBase_AUBase_h.html) code from Apple, a quick search on Github might be useful too (e.g. https://github.com/kbob/AudioUnitTemplates)

If you don't want to install the AU, you should refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2247/_index.html and [Audio units dynamic registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705405/audio-units-dynamic-registration/32309103#32309103)

Comment: Yes, I did. It seems like buffer passed into this is a copy of the original data, and does not affect the output sound even when I change this buffer.